# Request Apache Accumulo error help using Hadoop and Zookeeper in a test environment

Tags: hadoop, apache-zookeeper

I am setting up a test environment using apache accumulo ver 1.4.0, hadoop ver 0.20.2 and zookeeper ver 3.3.3.  Please see below for the issue.

Hadoop and Zookeeper work great together, but when I start accumulo using the procedures on apache incubator I get the following zookeeper stream of info and a warn:

```
2011-12-08 20:13:56,601 - INFO  [main:QuorumPeerConfig@90] - Reading configuration from: /home/hadoop/zookeeper-3.3.3/bin/../conf/zoo.cfg
2011-12-08 20:13:56,603 - WARN  [main:QuorumPeerMain@105] - Either no config or no quorum defined in config, running  in standalone mode
2011-12-08 20:13:56,616 - INFO  [main:QuorumPeerConfig@90] - Reading configuration from: /home/hadoop/zookeeper-3.3.3/bin/../conf/zoo.cfg
2011-12-08 20:13:56,617 - INFO  [main:ZooKeeperServerMain@94] - Starting server
2011-12-08 20:13:56,626 - INFO  [main:Environment@97] - Server environment:zookeeper.version=3.3.3-1073969, built on 02/23/2011 22:27 GMT
2011-12-08 20:13:56,627 - INFO  [main:Environment@97] - Server environment:host.name.paz
2011-12-08 20:13:56,627 - INFO  [main:Environment@97] - Server environment:java.version=1.6.0_26
2011-12-08 20:13:56,628 - INFO  [main:Environment@97] - Server environment:java.vendor=Sun Microsystems Inc.
2011-12-08 20:13:56,629 - INFO  [main:Environment@97] - Server environment:java.home=/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-1.6.0.26/jre
2011-12-08 20:13:56,629 - INFO  [main:Environment@97] - Server environment:java.class.path=/home/hadoop/zookeeper-3.3.3/bin/../build/classes:/home/hadoop/zookeeper-3.3.
3/bin/../build/lib/*.jar:/home/hadoop/zookeeper-3.3.3/bin/../zookeeper-3.3.3.jar:/home/hadoop/zookeeper-3.3.3/bin/../lib/log4j-1.2.15.jar:/home/hadoop/zookeeper-3.3.3/b
in/../lib/jline-0.9.94.jar:/home/hadoop/zookeeper-3.3.3/bin/../src/java/lib/*.jar:/home/hadoop/zookeeper-3.3.3/bin/../conf:
2011-12-08 20:13:56,630 - INFO  [main:Environment@97] - Server environment:java.library.path=/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-1.6.0.26/jre/lib/i386/server:/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-su
n-1.6.0.26/jre/lib/i386:/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-1.6.0.26/jre/../lib/i386:/usr/java/packages/lib/i386:/lib:/usr/lib
2011-12-08 20:13:56,630 - INFO  [main:Environment@97] - Server environment:java.io.tmpdir=/tmp
2011-12-08 20:13:56,631 - INFO  [main:Environment@97] - Server environment:java.compiler=<NA>
2011-12-08 20:13:56,631 - INFO  [main:Environment@97] - Server environment:os.name=Linux
2011-12-08 20:13:56,632 - INFO  [main:Environment@97] - Server environment:os.arch=i386
2011-12-08 20:13:56,633 - INFO  [main:Environment@97] - Server environment:os.version=3.0.0-13-generic
2011-12-08 20:13:56,633 - INFO  [main:Environment@97] - Server environment:user.name=hadoop
2011-12-08 20:13:56,634 - INFO  [main:Environment@97] - Server environment:user.home=/home/hadoop
2011-12-08 20:13:56,634 - INFO  [main:Environment@97] - Server environment:user.dir=/home/hadoop
2011-12-08 20:13:56,641 - INFO  [main:ZooKeeperServer@663] - tickTime set to 2000
2011-12-08 20:13:56,641 - INFO  [main:ZooKeeperServer@672] - minSessionTimeout set to -1
2011-12-08 20:13:56,642 - INFO  [main:ZooKeeperServer@681] - maxSessionTimeout set to -1
2011-12-08 20:13:56,661 - INFO  [main:NIOServerCnxn$Factory@143] - binding to port 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181
2011-12-08 20:13:56,691 - INFO  [main:FileSnap@82] - Reading snapshot /home/hadoop/zoo/dataDir/version-2/snapshot.0
2011-12-08 20:13:56,708 - INFO  [main:FileTxnSnapLog@208] - Snapshotting: 4e
2011-12-08 20:14:52,147 - INFO  [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181:NIOServerCnxn$Factory@251] - Accepted socket connection from /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:40694
2011-12-08 20:14:52,153 - INFO  [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181:NIOServerCnxn@777] - Client attempting to establish new session at /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:40694
2011-12-08 20:14:52,154 - INFO  [SyncThread:0:FileTxnLog@197] - Creating new log file: log.4f
2011-12-08 20:14:52,410 - INFO  [SyncThread:0:NIOServerCnxn@1580] - Established session 0x13420623ee70000 with negotiated timeout 30000 for client /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:4069
4
2011-12-08 20:14:52,959 - INFO  [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181:NIOServerCnxn$Factory@251] - Accepted socket connection from /127.0.0.1:38446
2011-12-08 20:14:52,962 - INFO  [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181:NIOServerCnxn@777] - Client attempting to establish new session at /127.0.0.1:38446
2011-12-08 20:14:53,007 - INFO  [SyncThread:0:NIOServerCnxn@1580] - Established session 0x13420623ee70001 with negotiated timeout 30000 for client /127.0.0.1:38446
2011-12-08 20:14:59,932 - WARN  [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181:NIOServerCnxn@634] - EndOfStreamException: Unable to read additional data from client session
id 0x13420623ee70000, likely client has closed socket
```

and when I start the accumulo shell I get the following errors:

```
18 12:44:38,746 [impl.ServerClient] WARN : Failed to find an available server in the list of servers: []
18 12:44:38,846 [impl.ServerClient] WARN : Failed to find an available server in the list of servers: []
18 12:44:38,947 [impl.ServerClient] WARN : Failed to find an available server in the list of servers: []
18 12:44:39,048 [impl.ServerClient] WARN : Failed to find an available server in the list of servers: []
18 12:44:39,148 [impl.ServerClient] WARN : Failed to find an available server in the list of servers: []
18 12:44:39,249 [impl.ServerClient] WARN : Failed to find an available server in the list of servers: []
18 12:44:39,350 [impl.ServerClient] WARN : Failed to find an available server in the list of servers: []
18 12:44:39,450 [impl.ServerClient] WARN : Failed to find an available server in the list of servers: []
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Corrected tserver memory settings to not exceed waht is allowed by the JVM.  Tserver does not crash and error resolved. 
Answer came from accumulo-incubator user list and is reposted at the bottom.
Basically, when going in and modifying memory settings to run in pseudo-distributed mode on a laptop I made incorrect modifications to the accumulo-site.xml and accumulo-env.sh files concerning the tablet server memory usage.  The clue to the error was found in the /home/hadoop/accumulo/logs/tserver*.log file:

```
20 18:20:00,951 [tabletserver.NativeMap] ERROR: Failed to load native
map library
/home/hadoop/accumulo/lib/native/map/libNativeMap-Linux-i386-32.so
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Can't load library:
/home/hadoop/accumulo/lib/native/map/libNativeMap-Linux-i386-32.so
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1706)
at java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:770)
at java.lang.System.load(System.java:1003)
at
org.apache.accumulo.server.tabletserver.NativeMap.loadNativeLib(NativeMap.java:144)
at
org.apache.accumulo.server.tabletserver.NativeMap.<clinit>(NativeMap.java:156)
at
org.apache.accumulo.server.tabletserver.TabletServerResourceManager.<init>(TabletServerResourceManager.java:123)
at
org.apache.accumulo.server.tabletserver.TabletServer.config(TabletServer.java:2959)
at
org.apache.accumulo.server.tabletserver.TabletServer.main(TabletServer.java:3085)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.apache.accumulo.start.Main$1.run(Main.java:89)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
20 18:20:00,999 [tabletserver.TabletServer] ERROR: Uncaught exception in
TabletServer.main, exiting
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Maximum tablet server map memory
134,217,728 and block cache sizes 186,646,528 is too large for this JVM
configuration 132,579,328
at
org.apache.accumulo.server.tabletserver.TabletServerResourceManager.<init>(TabletServerResourceManager.java:134)
at
org.apache.accumulo.server.tabletserver.TabletServer.config(TabletServer.java:2959)
at
org.apache.accumulo.server.tabletserver.TabletServer.main(TabletServer.java:3085)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.apache.accumulo.start.Main$1.run(Main.java:89)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Specific help text: 
"The native libraries are not loading, which is shifting in-memory
map into the java workspace. Add to that your block cache size, and your
specifications for memory use are higher than the JVM will be allowed to
allocate. The tablet servers complain, and exit. You should see these
complaints on the accumulo monitor web pages.

You may find a benefit to rebuilding the native map library, which will
move the allocation of the in-memory map to outside the JVM. This is
not required.

The size of any memory dedicated to cache must be smaller than the size
of the JVM, which must include substantial working space for RPC calls
and garbage collection over time."

Answer (score 0):

If you run the Zookeeper client (/home/hadoop/zookeeper-3.3.3/bin/zkCli.sh) and do an *ls* of

`/accumulo/<instance uuid>/tservers`

I assume you won't see any servers listed. You should see one or more tablet servers listed if Accumulo was initialized properly. Are you sure you ran the [Accumulo init script](http://incubator.apache.org/accumulo/user_manual_1.4-incubating/Administration.html#Initialization) after setting your Zookeeper servers in the *accumulo-site.xml* per the instructions?

Comment: Thank you for the reply.  You are correct - there are no tservers listed.  I have built this several times, and on several different linux boxes: Ubuntu and Centos, and followed the directions carefully.  The accumulo directory is created in HDFS after init, and the accumulo webpage is available from localhost:50095, but the tablet server count always stays at zero.  Any suggestions.

Comment: I would suggest posting your question and include your accumulo-site.xml and the log output to the [user mailing list](http://incubator.apache.org/accumulo/mailing_list.html). The developers are very helpful and responsive.

Comment: Thanks Jared. I will give the accumulo list a try...I had figured it was a zookeeper configuration error, but could be something I am not doing right in the accumulo set-up.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you set "instance.zookeeper.host" to the location of your zookeeper node in the accumulo-site.xml file.

Additionally, check the logs for your tservers and loggers. If you have other configuration issues, they will not go live, which will cause the master to report having difficulties finding tservers.

Answer (score 0):

Go into $ACCUMULO_HOME/conf . End the files masters,slaves and tracers to contain one single line that reads "localhost"  (I assume you are doing single node)